# html wrong position

Tags: html

I have no idea why this elements inner input field gets different rendering. This is a screenshot (it should be in the middle, like on firefox).

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/lasw.png/

The element exists out of 3 divs.

```
1. Container div (position relative)
2. Input field (position absolute; top: 3px; left 0px;)
3. Label (position absolute; top: 3px; left 0px;)
```

Here are the global styles (resetting and defining font style)

```
label, input, textarea, select, button{
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
}

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, menu,
time, mark, audio, video{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Here is the style on the container div:

```
.textbox{
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    border-image: initial;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Here is the style on the input field, placeholder:

```
.textboxInput, .textboxLabel{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Here is the style on the input field:

```
.textboxInput{
    background: none transparent !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
}
```

Here is the style of the label:

```
.textboxLabel{
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

I hope that some one knows why it is rendered differently.

The problem is not the font-weight, the difference is 2 pixels in Firefox and Chrome what is causing this?

Comment: There has to be a solution right?

Comment: can we working example so we can do some tricks that would be easy to find errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding-top and padding-bottom is added in firefox, removed that and got it working perfect.